# Remove Border around Button

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, button

I've been trying to remove the `Border` around a `Button` and also change the `Colour` of the `Button`'s `Background` when the mouse hovers over it.

Here is what I have:

```
<Button Name="Home" Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_Home" Background="#FF252525" FontFamily="/VideoManager;component/#Myriad Pro" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="5">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
           <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                   <Border BorderThickness="0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF36290A"/>
               </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

The issue is that regardless of what I set `BorderThickness` to, the `Button` disappears. Also the `Button` is not changing to the colour I specified with the `Trigger`.

I also tried simply using a `Style` `Setter` but found this had no effect on my `Button`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: You're missing `ContentPresenter` in your template but what's it the problem with the `BorderThickness`? If you set `BorderThickness="0"` you won't have border around content

Answer (score 0):

You need to define following `ControlTemplate` and remove Style Trigger.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border Name="border"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="#FF36290A" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I have tried this and this is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a style that I use to remove the default Windows style from buttons ; I'm sure you can use it or use it to achieve what you want. As it is, it just makes a button with absolutely no border, no background, no margins, nothing, just play with the template to achieve what you want :

```
<Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="0.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

It is not mine but I don't remember where I found it, so sorry if the author come by !

You could also take the default button template from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and tweak it.